# Reading in file to array and using it to initialize objects

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, file-io, polymorphism

I have 5 classes (they're small). PersonDemo (test class), Person (superclass), and Student, Instructor and Graduate Student (sub classes). All the classes except for PersonDemo are finished.

I need to read in a file (data.txt) and store it to array Person. Then need I need to determine which object to initialize depending on the first value of the array. ( 1 - person, 2 - student, 3 - instructor or 4 - graduate student ) - I'm having trouble with this part.

Can someone point me in the right direction? My classes are below along with what the input file (data.txt) looks like and what the output file should look like.

[image: input output]

**PersonDemo.Java**

```
public class PersonDemo
{
    public static void main () 
    {
     JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
     Scanner fileScanner = null; 
     Person [] ins = new Person [10];

     try {
     if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
     {
       File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile(); 
       fileScanner = new Scanner(selectedFile);

       while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) 
       {
        // Need to load "data.txt" into array 
        // Then need I need to determine which object to initialize depending on the 
        // first value of the array in "data.txt"
        //( 1 - person, 2 - student, 3 - instructor or 4 - graduate student )
       }

       fileScanner.close();
     }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
     {
      System.out.println("Could not find file"); 
     }
    }

    public static void showAll(Person [] ins)
    {
      // Future code here
    }
}
```

**Person.java (superclass)**

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Person()
   {
       name="";
       age=0;
   }

   public Person(String name, int age)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }

   public String getName()
   {   
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name)
   {   
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getAge()
   {   
      return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age)
   {   
      this.age = age;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "Name: " + name + "\t" + "Age: " + age;
   }

}
```

**Student.java (subclass)**

```
public class Student extends Person
{
    private int studentID; 
    private String major;

   public Student()
   {
      studentID = 0; 
      major = "";
   }

   public Student(String name, int age, int studentID, String major)
   {
      super(name, age);
      this.major = major;
      this.studentID = studentID; 
   }

   public int getID()
   {
      return studentID; 
   }

    public void setID(int studentID)
   {
     this.studentID = studentID; 
   }

   public String getMajor()
   {
     return major;
   }

   public void setMajor(String major)
   {
     this.major = major; 
   }

   public String toString()
   {
     return super.toString() + "Student ID: " + studentID + "Major: " + major;
   }
}
```

**GraduateStudent.java (subclass)**

```
public class GraduateStudent extends Student
{
   private String researchArea; 

   public GraduateStudent()
   {
      researchArea = ""; 
   }

   public GraduateStudent(String name, int age, int studentID, String major, String researchArea)
   {
      super(name, age, studentID, major); 
      this.researchArea = researchArea; 
   }

   public String getArea()
   {
      return researchArea;  
   }

   public void setArea(String researchArea)
   {
     this.researchArea = researchArea; 
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return super.toString() + "Research Area: " + researchArea;
   }
}
```

**Instructor.java (subclass)**

```
public class Instructor extends Person
{
   private int salary; 

   public Instructor()
   {
      salary = 0; 
   }

   public Instructor(String name, int age, int salary)
   {
      super(name, age); 
      this.salary = salary; 
   }

   public int getSalary()
   {
      return salary; 
   }

   public void setSalary(int salary)
   {
      this.salary = salary; 
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return super.toString() + "Salary: " + salary;
   }

}
```

Comment: Step 1:  make your program able to parse all the types of lines

Comment: You must write code to read each line, parse it into fields, and then test the value of the first field to decide which constructor to invoke.  However, we are not going to write that for you.  The way SO works is you write the code and then when you run into a problem, post what you have tried and we will answer specific questions.